# Rails4 how to pass variable within controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Ransack in a Rails 4 app to search records on an index list.

I then have a button on that index list linking to a scoresgraph page.

I want to use the @scores from the index in the `scores graph`.

Here is the scores controller:

```
def index
  @search = current_user.scores.notarchived.search(params[:q])
  @scores = @search.result
end

def scoresgraph
  @scores = params[:scores]
end
```

This is the button in the index page:

```
<%= link_to 'Graph', scores_scoresgraph_path(:scores => @scores), :class => 'btn btn-xs btn-primary' %>
```

But, I'm getting: undefined method `order' for "#Score::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007fb5bdbf9a08":String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should extract what is inside index into a separated method:

```
def index
  @scores = score
end

def scoresgraph
  @scores = score
end

private

def search
  @search ||= current_user.scores.notarchived.search(params[:q])
end

def score
  search.result
end
```

If this does not work, it may be because in the scoresgraph you don't have reference to the old variables, so you should change the link_to to:

```
<%= link_to 'Graph', scores_scoresgraph_path(q: 'same q as the index'), :class => 'btn btn-xs btn-primary' %>
```

Comment: I passed the search param q. Thanks!